# Minimal givens of a Fill-a-Pix/Mosaic Puzzles

Tags: matrices, reference-request, puzzle

Recently, I solved some **Fill-a-Pix Puzzles** (or also called **Mosaic Puzzles**) and got fascinated by the techniques to solve a puzzle.
For those who don't know the rules to solve such a puzzle, you can follow [this link](https://www.conceptispuzzles.com/index.aspx?uri=puzzle/fill-a-pix) or just comprehend the following mathematical description of the problem (which I need to formulate my problem):

> **Definition** Let $A = (a_{ij}) \in M_{m,n}(\{0,1\})$ and $\mathcal{M}_A = (m_{ij}) \in M_{m,n}(\{0,\dots,9\})$ be the matrix defined by
>   $$m_{ij} = \Big| \big\{ a_{kl} \, \big| \,  |k-i|\leq 1, |l-j|\leq 1, a_{kl} = 1   \big\} \Big|.$$
>   Let us call $A$ the **picture matrix** and $\mathcal{M}_A$ the corresponding **data matrix**.

**Example**

If $$A = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 1 & 0 & 1 \\ 1 & 1 & 0 \end{pmatrix},$$ then
$$
\mathcal{M}_A = \begin{pmatrix} 2 & 3 & 2 \\ 4 & 5 & 3 \\ 3 & 4 & 2 \end{pmatrix}.
$$

**Observations and Thoughts**

1. Not every matrix can be a data matrix, for instance there is no picture matrix $A \in M_{1,2}(\{0,1\})$ such that
   $
   \mathcal{M}_A = \begin{pmatrix}
   0 & 2
   \end{pmatrix}
   $.
2. <strike>It is not hard to show that if $\require{enclose} \enclose{horizontalstrike}{M}$ is a data matrix, then there is a unique matrix $\require{enclose} \enclose{horizontalstrike}{A}$ such that $\require{enclose} \enclose{horizontalstrike}{M = \mathcal{M}_A}$. A proof via induction is the key.</strike>  (This observation is wrong, see 5.)
3. Let $M$ be a data matrix. Sometimes it suffices to not even know all entries of $M$ and still get a unique picture matrix corresponding to $M$ (this is exactly how this puzzle works).
   For example, if $$
   M = \begin{pmatrix}* & * & * \\ * & 9 & * \\ * & * & * \end{pmatrix},$$ then the unique matrix $A$ with $M = \mathcal{M}_A$ is
   $$
   A = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 & 1 \\ 1 & 1 & 1 \\ 1 & 1 & 1 \end{pmatrix}.
   $$
4. This does not always work though. To be more explicit: If we only know few entries of the data matrix, it can correspond to more than one possible picture matrices. An example is
   $$
   M = \begin{pmatrix}
   * & * & * \\ * & 8 & * \\ * & * & * 
   \end{pmatrix}.
   $$
   Here, both $M = \mathcal{M}_A$ and $M = \mathcal{M}_B$ where
   $$
   A = \begin{pmatrix}
    1 & 0 & 1 \\ 1 & 1 & 1 \\ 1 & 1 & 1
   \end{pmatrix} \quad \text{or} \quad B = \begin{pmatrix}
    0 & 1 & 1 \\ 1 & 1 & 1 \\ 1 & 1 & 1
   \end{pmatrix}
   $$
   are possible solutions, depending, for instance, on the upper left entry of $M$.
5. Even if we know all entries of the data matrix $M$, there might be different matrices $A$ and $B$ with $\mathcal{M}_A = M = \mathcal{M}_B$ as *Jaap Scherphuis* pointed out in the comments (and this is why observation 2. is wrong). I will put his example here: If $M = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 \end{pmatrix}$, then both $A = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}$ and $A = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$ satisfy $\mathcal{M}_A = M = \mathcal{M}_B$ despite $A \neq B$.

**Assumption**: From now on, we suppose $M$ is a data matrix for which there is exactly one corresponding picture matrix.

> **Question** Given a data matrix $M$, what is the minimal number of entries of $M$ I need to know, such that I can find a unique picture matrix $A$ such that $M = \mathcal{M}_A$?

Is there any mathematics done on this problem already? If not, is there a similar problem where people have done research on it?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: This puzzle is similar to a *nonogram*, which you can solve via integer linear programming, as described in [this blog post](https://blogs.sas.com/content/operations/2015/12/14/solving-the-british-spy-agencys-christmas-puzzle/).

Comment: Nonograms are similarly interesting and it is good to know how to solve them. However, this does not seem to address my question about the minimality.

Comment: The [minimum number of clues](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematics_of_Sudoku#Minimum_number_of_givens) has been determined for Sudoku.  Minesweeper is also similar to Fill-a-Pix and has been researched with respect to NP-completeness, but I don't know about minimality.

Comment: I don't think observation 2 is correct. For example for $\mathcal{M}_A = \begin{pmatrix}
1 & 1
\end{pmatrix}$ we could have $A = \begin{pmatrix}
0 & 1
\end{pmatrix}$ or $A = \begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0
\end{pmatrix}$, so $A$ is not always unique.

Comment: In fact, with minor exceptions, non-uniqueness applies to any matrix with $2$ rows (or $2$ columns), since $m_{1j} = m_{2j}$ for all $j$ and the $M$ matrix cannot distinguish (resolve) the different rows of $A$.

Answer (score 0):

Not an answer / just a long comment on non-uniqueness.

In fact, if the number of rows $m$, or the number of columns $n$, is of the form $3k+2$, then there exists $M$ matrices with multiple $A$ solutions.  E.g. for $n=8$ here are three $A$ matrices:

```
01001001
01001001
01001001
01001001

10010010
10010010
10010010
10010010

10010010
10010010
01001001
10010010
```

which have the same $M$ matrix:

```
2222222
3333333
3333333
2222222
```

The underlying reason is that when $n=3k+2$, the $mn$ equations are not linearly dependent, since a single row (of length $n$) can be "decomposed" in two ways:

```
(..)(...)(...)
      vs
(...)(...)(..)
```

so we have $M_{i1} + M_{i4} + M_{i7} = M_{i2} + M_{i5} + M_{i8}$ for every row $i$.  Now, the $mn$ equations being linearly dependent means there can be multiple solutions in $\mathbb{R}^{m\times n}$, but the examples show there can also be multiple solutions even in $\{0,1\}^{m\times n}$.

---

Obviously, this doesn't answer the OP question, but in light of this, we might have to find a way to characterize which $M$ admits a unique solution $A$, before we ask the further question of when a partial view of such an $M$ also admits a unique solution $A$...?

Comment: Thanks for the input, [I created another post for this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3496699/when-does-the-data-of-a-fill-a-pix-mosaic-puzzle-give-a-unique-picture).