# When does the data of a Fill-a-Pix/Mosaic Puzzle give a unique picture?

Tags: matrices, reference-request, puzzle

This question is motivated by my wrong observation 2. of [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3495621/minimal-givens-of-a-fill-a-pix-mosaic-puzzles). For reasons of clarity, I am going to put the same set up here too:

> **Definition** Let $A = (a_{ij}) \in M_{m,n}(\{0,1\})$ and $\mathcal{M}_A = (m_{ij}) \in M_{m,n}(\{0,\dots,9\})$ be the matrix defined by
>   $$m_{ij} = \Big| \big\{ a_{kl} \, \big| \,  |k-i|\leq 1, |l-j|\leq 1, a_{kl} = 1   \big\} \Big|.$$
>   Let us call $A$ the **picture matrix** and $\mathcal{M}_A$ the corresponding **data matrix**.

**Example**

If $$A = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 1 & 0 & 1 \\ 1 & 1 & 0 \end{pmatrix},$$ then
$$
\mathcal{M}_A = \begin{pmatrix} 2 & 3 & 2 \\ 4 & 5 & 3 \\ 3 & 4 & 2 \end{pmatrix}.
$$

**Observations and Thoughts**

1. Not every matrix can be a data matrix, for instance there is no picture matrix $A \in M_{1,2}(\{0,1\})$ such that
   $
   \mathcal{M}_A = \begin{pmatrix}
   0 & 2
   \end{pmatrix}
   $.
2. It is also not necessary that a data matrix $M$ admits a unique corresponding picture matrix. For instance (cf. *Jaap Scherphuis*'s comment in the [mentioned link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3495621/minimal-givens-of-a-fill-a-pix-mosaic-puzzles)), if $M = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 \end{pmatrix}$, then both $A = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}$ and $A = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$ are possible solutions for $\mathcal{M}_A = M$.
3. User *antkam* noted that if a data has $3k+2$ rows (or columns), it has more than one corresponding picture matrix, [see here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3496254).

> **Question** Under which circumstance does a data matrix $M$ admit a unique corresponding picture matrix?

Further thoughts, references and remarks are highly appreciated!